# Show number of users who maxed out their daily review quota on a queue in the stats

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, statistics

In "rare reviews" daily stats we can actually see who did all reviews they could (20), quickly followed by users who have not reached the maximum amount of points, so the list helps to see who was most active on these review queues (as of this writing: [Late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats), [Help and improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/stats), [Reopen votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats) fit this description).

For the others it's just a long list of 20 of 40. It's not as fun. Could we see the number of users who achieved the daily limit on a queue?

Comment: I'm really curious to know how many users are doing their utmost in the close votes queue.