# Can we see the total number of people who have done the maximum reviews?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, statistics

Posting this here instead of on MSE because most other sites don't have this many reviewers.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats

[image]

I'm sure lots more people than that reviewed 40 close votes today. Given that list caps on the page height, it would be nice to see the total number of people that have hit the cap today.

I'm just trying to get an idea of how many new close votes are being generated and how many people are participating. Are most people that participate only doing a few? Should we be trying to get more reviewers, or the current reviewers to do more per day, or what?

Comment: You get informed of the total number of reviews for the day. You could get maximum and minimum users from that, and then invent a figure somewhere in between.

Comment: @BillWoodger: You could, but it wouldn't be real accurate since I virtually guarantee the curve doesn't follow any trivially-guessable distribution and there's no data most of us can access to figure out what distribution to use. Might as well just make up numbers without bothering with the intermediate steps.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Firstly, I didn't read the question. I thought it was "how many people reviewed at least one item on a given day"-type thing. It's not, it's "how many people reached 40". I actually think that for that, the scheme is going to be pretty accurate (divide total reviews by 40, and it won't really be far off, and not in a consequential way for "evaluating" things). Do it for the five working-days, and the weekend (separately). There's no evidence of the existence of a massive tail of users who do one review and then think they've done their bit for the day.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Secondly, having misread the question it was "I need this figure" even when you know that figure is not actually reliably attainable. There are people who don't give up even when it is explained that there is no way to know. For those, you take the maxima and minima, and "guess" somewhere in the middle. To put it another way, delegating the task "well, tell him something, and make sure it can't be proved wrong". SOP for people who want an accurate answer to a dumb-in-that-context question. Sorry for that durron597, but go with the first bit.

Comment: @BillWoodger: From what I've seen in Late Answers, there is indeed a nice long tail of users that don't all get their 20 reviews in. Partly in that case it's because the queue has so little traffic relative to available reviewers; partly other reasons. For other queues, there's no evidence of the long tail precisely *because we can't hope to see it*, which just proves my point about the truly execrable accuracy of any distributions we might care to hang on it. There's very little data here. Attempting to use the principle of indifference or whatever else isn't going to help.

Comment: @NathanTuggy As I understood it, the question was about Close. If there are 40 users who do one review, that only "disguises" what would otherwise be considered one reviewer. This request isn't going to happen. It's not going to get any development resource attached to it (my guess). Look at the reasons for the feature-request in the final paragraph.

Comment: 747 reviews done today. I've just added three to that. 13 users have done 40 reviews. The non-40 top reviewers total 177 reviews. That comes to 697 reviews by those on that page., so 50 by others. Just dividing by 40 will be pretty accurate (for what is required). Sure, Saturday morning is a bad time to check in one way, but good in another, as the tail is clearly visible and has no real impact on any necessary granularity of the answer for the purpose stated ("it would be nice to know as the answer may somehow feed into my indistinct questions about something", a paraphrase).

Comment: If deeply interested, copy/paste, screenprint/scrape at every some-time-unit (modified through experience) and do the work. You'll get a completely accurate answer for how many reach 40 in that day (at the cost of being available at those keys points during the day). Again, do that for five working days, and the weekend (separately).

Comment: This made me want to go out and do 40 reviews. ++me to the list.

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293761/show-number-of-users-who-maxed-out-their-daily-review-quota-on-a-queue-in-the-st, but damn you worded it way better.

Comment: @Kyll dupes do not *necessarily* have to close the newer question, just usually.

Comment: Great idea. Robo-reviewers really deserve to see their names on a leaderboard, don't forget to add the time it took them to blast through the maximum.

Comment: @TheBlueDog I get pretty good at it, yeah. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @rene Remember, second place is the first loser

Comment: @TheBlueDog What evidence do you have that people who review 40 items are robo-reviewing?

Comment: @TylerH: What evidence do you have that they are not? ;)

Comment: @TheBlueDog The burden of proof lies with the one making the claim.

Comment: @TylerH: I actually posted that as a rather tongue-in-cheek dig at those who blindly review and approve ghastly edits, it certainly wasn't intended as a slur against the more serious reviewers. However, if you want evidence, just hang out in `PHP` or `VB.Net` for a day or two ...

Comment: What exactly does this new statistic try to solve?  Seeing that 50 people hit the cap, does what exactly?  Not everyone wants to spend an huge amount of time in the review queues and reviewing 40 questions takes time.  I'm not sure what the benefit of this is.